# Dozer 5.3.2. Programmatically set custom converters?

Tags: java, dozer

How do I programmatically set custom converter for dozer? The following code doesn't work:

Custom Converter implementation:

```
class ConverterImpl extends DozerConverter<A, B> {

ConverterImpl() {
    super(A.class, B.class);
}

@Override
public B convertTo(A source, B destination) {
    return destination;
}

@Override
public A convertFrom(B source, A destination) {
    return destination;
}
}
```

Test code:

```
DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.setCustomConverters(Collections.<CustomConverter>singletonList(new ConverterImpl()));
A a = new A(); 
B b = mapper.map(a, A.class);
```

After running the code above, custom converter doesn't get invoked. What is wrong?

Comment: Aren't the converters for the **fields** of `A` or `B`, not the entire class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have to actually add a specific mapping, and unfortunately you can only specify field-level converters, not class-level converters, using the programmatic API. So if you wrap the A and B classes in container classes, you can specify a mapping for the A and B fields.

For example the following verbose code works as expected:

```
public class DozerMap {

   public static class ContainerA {
      private A a;
      public A getA() { return a; }
      public void setA(A a) { this.a = a; }
   }

   public static class ContainerB {
      private B b;
      public B getB() { return b; }
      public void setB(B b) { this.b = b; }
   }

   private static class A { };

   private static class B { };

   static class ConverterImpl extends DozerConverter<A, B> {

      ConverterImpl() {
         super(A.class, B.class);
      }

      @Override
      public B convertTo(A source, B destination) {
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Invoked");
         return destination;
      }

      @Override
      public A convertFrom(B source, A destination) {
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Invoked");
         return destination;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
      mapper.setCustomConverters(Collections.<CustomConverter> singletonList(new ConverterImpl()));
      BeanMappingBuilder foo = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

         @Override
         protected void configure() {
            mapping(ContainerA.class, ContainerB.class).fields("a", "b", FieldsMappingOptions.customConverter(ConverterImpl.class));
         }
      };
      mapper.setMappings(Collections.singletonList(foo));
      ContainerA containerA = new ContainerA();
      containerA.a = new A();
      ContainerB containerB = mapper.map(containerA, ContainerB.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the API has changed in 5.5.1. I could not find a method for mapper.setMappings(Collections.singletonList(foo));  Instead I used mapper.addMapping(foo);

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to set it programatically ? I mean do you have any specific needs ? Otherwise, Mapping via an xml file works fine.

In case you want to do it more in a programing way , rather through some xml configuration files, Check out  [Orika](http://code.google.com/p/orika/wiki/GettingStartedGuide).

It has good API support.

Comment: he's trying to map the classes without specifying the particular class fields